# How can I select the temporal resolution of my datetime x-ticks in my matplotlib pyplot plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently plotting a temporal series using `pyplot`. I have specified the following x-ticks, which consist of four objects of type `datetime`:

```py
x_ticks
array(['2021-10-17T09:23:11.000000', '2021-10-17T10:02:15.750000',
       '2021-10-17T10:41:20.500000', '2021-10-17T11:20:25.250000'],
      dtype='datetime64[us]')
```

As you can see, each element (purposely) has a time resolution down to microseconds.
So far, so good. However, when I actually get to plot my graph of interest, by default the time axis appears with format YYYY-MM-DD, like in the image below:

[image]

It automatically crops the hours and seconds, but I would like to visualize them. How can I specify the resolution of my time x-ticks that needs to appear in the plots?

Comment: updated post from subplots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DateFormatter to set the display of the axis. I also used a LinearLocator to show not all labels, in this case it's 4. And rotated the labels to take up less space with autofmt_xdate().

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates

aaa = np.array(['2021-10-17T09:23:11.000000', '2021-10-17T10:02:15.750000',
       '2021-10-17T10:41:20.500000', '2021-10-17T11:20:25.250000'],
      dtype='datetime64[us]')

bbb = [1, 3, 7, 5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(aaa, bbb)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
locator = matplotlib.ticker.LinearLocator(4)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

If subplots with captions are needed, although this was not visible in the question, then the solution is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, constrained_layout=True, figsize=(7, 7))

aaa = np.array(['2021-10-17T09:23:11.000000', '2021-10-17T10:02:15.750000',
       '2021-10-17T10:41:20.500000', '2021-10-17T11:20:25.250000'],
      dtype='datetime64[us]')
bbb = [1, 3, 7, 5]

lims = aaa[0], aaa[-1]
form = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
locator = matplotlib.ticker.LinearLocator(4)

for nn, ax in enumerate(axs):
    ax.plot(aaa, bbb)
    ax.set_xlim(lims)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(form)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(7)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @inquirer! Thank you so much for your suggestion. What you propose is indeed correct but it is not perfect with subplots since it just includes the axis on the last subplot. Do you know if there is a way to show axes for each of the subplots?